# Google Maps strange behavior swift 4 ios

Tags: swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios, xcode10

**Update**: Dose it have to do anything with language? as my app is sporting English and Arabic.

Hi everyone I am struggling with this since days and I have tried everything but can not find any solution, the problem is when I run the app through xCode it all works fine like in the following screenshot. 
[image: working maps]

Then when i unplug the device and reopen the app it stops working, the app is running fine but i dont see any map but just the markers like the following screenshot.
[image: not working map]

Any help will be appreciated.

AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(googleApiKey)
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(googleApiKey)       
    return true

}
```

ViewController

```swift
     //Step 1
     @IBOutlet weak var mapview: GMSMapView!

      //Step 2
     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            self.mapview.settings.scrollGestures = true
            self.mapview.settings.zoomGestures = true
            self.mapview.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            self.mapview.settings.myLocationButton = true
            self.mapview.delegate = self
            self.mapview.layoutIfNeeded()

        }

    }

    //Step 3 After we have the current location items are loaded from server by user location and the markers are added in GetBusinesses function
    extension ItemsList: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else {
                return
            }
                self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

                self.mapview.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target:  (self.locationManager.location?.coordinate)!, zoom: 14, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
                self.GetBusinesses(data: "&isOpen=2&cat=\(Prefrences.getSelectedCategoryId())")
        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem occurs when you run the application separated from xCode

Comment: have you tried to delete the application on the device rebuild it and unplug it then run it ?

Comment: The app is installed using xcode and when i close the app from recent apps stack and when i reopen it, i get this kind of map

Comment: this problem could be that when u load the view again the map doesn't load in proper way can u add some code example please

Comment: Yes i have tried cleaning app and rebuilding, deleting and installing again, generating ipa and installing it manually it gave me same result ☹️

Comment: please add code on where you call the map and  populate it

Comment: Yup hang on a second

Comment: Kindly check the updated question.

Comment: first things first please try to change the place of             self.mapview.delegate = self move it to the ViewDidLoad and try again

Comment: It was there i just added it in viewDidAppear to test if it might help! anyways its same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180433/discussion-between-tobi-and-ussaid-iqbal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after struggling many days and trying every stupid possible way to fix it, I finally found a solution to it. The main problem was if your app is supporting multiple languages then google map will show this kind of behaviour. Following are the steps to fix it.

**Step 1:** 
If you have the GMSMapView view in your viewController, **break the outlets** of your GMSMapView since it will be created **dynamically**.

**Step 2:** 
Set the application language as per the user settings.

**Step 3:** 
Create custom GMSMapView object set delegate methods and other necessary settings and add it to its container.

That's it, you are good to go. What I understood from this is that you have to set your app language first before creating the GMSMapView (*I can be wrong as well*). If anyone knows why this method is working kindly explain it.

```swift
    //Our Custom MapView Var
    var mapview: GMSMapView!


    //View viewDidLoad() function
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            /*
              TODO: 
              Get selected language from preferences and set accordingly. 
            */
            UserDefaults.standard.set(["en"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 55.277397,
                                                  longitude: 25.199514,
                                                  zoom:12)
            self.mapview = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.mMapContainer.bounds, camera: camera)
            self.mapview.delegate = self
            self.mapview.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            self.mapview.settings.myLocationButton = true
            self.mapview.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            self.mapview.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            mMapContainer.addSubview(self.mapview)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

to show map in custom views you have to do it that way,

```
 let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lat , longitude: long, zoom: 15.0)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 2, width: self.MapView.frame.width - 4, height: self.MapView.frame.height - 2), camera: camera)
    self.MapView.addSubview(mapView)
    self.MapView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.MapView.contentMode = .center
```

you need to create  a mapView using the created mapView on the storyboard frame and add it as a subView in the main MapView you created

Comment: I am sorry I have tried that way too, what I think the problem is, it's that my app is multi language and when I create a project with one default language it all works fine. So if u have any idea how to manage multi language with Google maps

Comment: i don't really get it, language has nothing to do with the google maps  you can request it in any language

Comment: I created another project and when I added Arabic language it started same thing again 

Comment: well i am going to add this to my fav list, i really want to know an answer for this